# How can I call a method from QMainWindow?

Tags: qt, c++11, windows-10, qt5, moc

I do need to invoke a method from my MainWindow class, that inherit from [`QMainWindow`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html) class from a class outside MainWindow, something like this:

```
Q_ASSERT(QMetaObject::invokeMethod(mainWindow, "attachmentDownloadComplete"));
```

`mainWindow` is of class `MainWindow : public QMainWindow` type

the error is:

```
no matching function for call to 'QMetaObject::invokeMethod(MainWindow*&, const char [27])'
     Q_ASSERT(QMetaObject::invokeMethod(mainWindow, "attachmentDownloadComplete"));
```

My question is how can I manage to call invoke this method?

Comment: Are you sure you declared `attachmentDownloadComplete` as signal or slot?

Comment: Yes, it's declared as slot.

Comment: Can you show how you've declared it?

Comment: What is `NAMEOF`?

Comment: Have you included the header file where `MainWindow` is defined? Is this the complete error message? Often the compiler suggest some available alternative syntaxes.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should not put function calls inside of the `Q_ASSERT` macro, since the entire call will be skipped in Release builds.

Comment: Why you don't want to call method directly? You already have a pointer to mainWindow instance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, the slot you are trying to invoke has an input argument.

When you have an input argument you need to specify the argument with `Q_ARG.`

ex:

In my main window I have a slot, as shown below.

```
public slots:

    void doSomeTest(const char* name) { std::cout << "testing Something"; }
```

In some other file when invoking it, should do as said below.
Tested and working as expected.

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(mainWin, "doSomeTest", Q_ARG(const char*, "test test"));
```

First parameter - Your main window object.

Second parameter - The slot name.

From third on all your input parameters with types.

If you have any return type use

```
Q_RETURN_ARG(RETURN_TYPE, RETURN_VALUE_PARAMETER),
```